# Trying to switch the context of GraphicsContext in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm creating a small paint program using JavaFX. I've successfully implemented free drawing on the canvas. However, I also want to be able to draw straight lines from the point that I click to when my mouse is depressed. I create a line beforehand, however I can't seem to switch context so that I will only draw straight lines instead of free drawing.

At the moment, if I was to click my "straight line" button, it draws one straight line and then defaults back to free drawing while throwing a lot of errors. Could you help?

Here's my code for free drawing:

```
paintScene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
        gc.stroke();
    });

    paintScene.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
        gc.stroke();
    });
```

(where gc is the GraphicsContext)

This is my create a straight line functionality:

```
    Line l = new Line(20, 30, 30, 20);
    l.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    l.setStrokeWidth(10);

       straightLineBtn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            paintScene.setOnMousePressed(event1 -> {
              canvasHolder.getChildren().addAll(l);
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to test your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the line to update, until you release the mouse button. This means you either have to store data about everything that was drawn before or you need draw a `Line` `Node` on top of the canvas. I recommend the later approach.

**Example code**

```
private static class LineDrawListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private LineDrawListener(Canvas canvas, Pane canvasPane) {
        this.canvasPane = canvasPane;
        this.gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        line = new Line();
        line.setStrokeWidth(10);
        line.setManaged(true);
        line.setMouseTransparent(true);

        releasedHandler = evt -> {
            // remove line from canvas parent and draw line on canvas instead
            canvasPane.getChildren().remove(line);
            Point2D start = canvas.parentToLocal(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY());
            Point2D end = canvas.parentToLocal(line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
            gc.setLineWidth(10);
            gc.strokeLine(start.getX(), start.getY(), end.getX(), end.getY());
            removeListeners();
        };
        draggedHandler = evt -> {
            // update end of line
            line.setEndX(evt.getX());
            line.setEndY(evt.getY());
        };
        pressedHandler = evt -> {
            // add line to canvas parent
            canvasPane.getChildren().add(line);
            line.setStartX(evt.getX());
            line.setStartY(evt.getY());
            line.setEndX(evt.getX());
            line.setEndY(evt.getY());
        };
    }

    private final GraphicsContext gc;
    private final Pane canvasPane;
    private final Line line;

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> pressedHandler;

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> draggedHandler;

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> releasedHandler;

    private void removeListeners() {
        canvasPane.setOnMousePressed(null);
        canvasPane.setOnMouseDragged(null);
        canvasPane.setOnMouseReleased(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        canvasPane.setOnMousePressed(pressedHandler);
        canvasPane.setOnMouseDragged(draggedHandler);
        canvasPane.setOnMouseReleased(releasedHandler);
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);

    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
    clip.widthProperty().bind(canvas.widthProperty());
    clip.heightProperty().bind(canvas.heightProperty());

    Pane canvasPane = new Pane(canvas);
    canvasPane.setClip(clip);

    Button btn = new Button("Draw Line");
    LineDrawListener listener = new LineDrawListener(canvas, canvasPane);
    btn.setOnAction(listener);

    VBox root = new VBox(btn, canvasPane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
canvasHolder.getChildren().addAll(l);
```

Tries to add the same line `l` to the `canvasHolder` on each click.

It is forbidden to add same component to the components tree multiple times. You should create and add a new `Line` on each click.

You define both `onMousePressed` and `onMouseDragged` handlers for *free drawing* mode, and replaces only `onMousePressed` for *straight line* mode. This leads to that instead of pure *straight line* mode, some combination of modes are activated. To fix this, you should either remove `onMouseDragged` handler, or redefine it in the same way as `onMousePressed` one.

Comment: Hi @kgeorgiy, is this more like it: canvasHolder.getChildren().addAll(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY()));?

Comment: I tried what you said, but it's still allowing free draw to take place.

Comment: Added clarifiction

Comment: Okay, will try now.